# How can I select an area to screengrab in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, screenshot

I recently moved to Lubuntu 18.04.3 "Bionic Beaver" and found that `alt` + `PrtSc` will screen grab the active window.
On Mint and Ubuntu, this key combination lets you manually select which part of the screen to capture,  similar to the Snipping Tool on Windows.

How can I enable this functionality on my machine? It saves a lot of time having to crop images in GIMP.

Comment: Please mention the version of Lubuntu. The output of `cat /var/log/installer/media-info` will tell you that.

Comment: I've updated the question with my version

Comment: Worked very well. Thank you! Just that I had to go to Preferences - Setup Hot Keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Lubuntu 19.10. The default tool is `screengrab`. Running `screengrab --help` shows the available options:

```
Options:
  -h, --help        Displays this help.
  -v, --version     Displays version information.
  -f, --fullscreen  Take a fullscreen screenshot
  -a, --active      Take a screenshot of the active window
  -r, --region      Take a screenshot of a selection of the screen
  -m, --minimized   Run the application with a hidden main window
```

Instead of opening a terminal and running something like `sleep 5 && screengrab -r` which will launch screengrab after 5s to allow you to minimize the terminal window and view the region you're interested, it is worth making a keyboard shortcut for the purpose.

To make this shortcut, click on Lubuntu's Menu icon (usually located at the left end of your panel) and then open *Preferences > LXQt settings > Shortcut keys*. I've chosen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (where <kbd>Meta</kbd> is the *Windows* or *Super* key and *I* is for interactive.

**Setting a shortcut for taking a screenshot of *a selected area**

[image: Setting a shortcut for taking a screenshot of *a selected area]

Once you save the shortcut, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, you'll see this which is self-explanatory:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! After some fiddling, I set up `scrot -s` as my `alt`+`PrtSc` shortcut!